# How to fix Community Connector Error in look studio?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio, connector

I created api connector myself.

This is Code.gs file.

```
var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
function getAuthType() {
  var AuthTypes = cc.AuthType;
  return cc
    .newAuthTypeResponse()
    .setAuthType(AuthTypes.NONE)
    .build();
}
function getConfig(request) {
  var config = cc.getConfig();
  
  config.newInfo()
    .setId('instructions')
    .setText('Enter api url to get data , api token , username and password');
  
  config.newTextInput()
    .setId('api_url')
    .setName('Enter a api url')
    .setPlaceholder('https://');
  config.newTextInput()
    .setId('api_key')
    .setName('Enter a Api Key')
    .setHelpText('e.g. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  config.newTextInput()
    .setId('username')
    .setName('Enter a username');
  config.newTextInput()
    .setId('password')
    .setName('Enter a username')
    .setType('password');
  
  return config.build();
}
function getFields(request) {
  var cc = DataStudioApp.createCommunityConnector();
  var fields = cc.getFields();
  var types = cc.FieldType;
  var aggregations = cc.AggregationType;
  
  fields.newDimension()
    .setId('username')
    .setType(types.TEXT);
  
  fields.newMetric()
    .setId('version')
    .setType(types.NUMBER);
  
  fields.newDimension()
    .setId('address')
    .setType(types.TEXT);
  
  return fields;
}

function getSchema(request) {
  var fields = getFields(request).build();
  return { schema: fields };
}
function responseToRows(requestedFields, response) {
  // Transform parsed data and filter for requested fields
  return response.map(function(data) {
    var row = [];
    requestedFields.asArray().forEach(function (field) {
      switch (field.getId()) {
        case 'username':
          return row.push(data.result.user.createdByName);
        case 'version':
          return row.push(data.result.user.version);
        case 'address':
          return row.push(data.result.user.address);
        default:
          return row.push('');
      }
    });
    return { values: row };
  });
}

function getData(request) {

  var requestedFieldIds = request.fields.map(function(field) {
    return field.name;
  });
  var requestedFields = getFields().forIds(requestedFieldIds);

  // Fetch and parse data from API
  const API_KEY = request.configParams.api_key;
  var url = request.configParams.api_url;

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    "headers":{ "api-key": API_KEY },
    "payload": "{username:\""+request.configParams.username+"\", password: \""+request.configParams.password+"\"}",
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
  var rows = responseToRows(requestedFields, parsedResponse);

  return {
    schema: requestedFields.build(),
    rows: rows
  };
}
```

data from api in postman.

```
{
 "result": {
    "user": {
        "type": "User",
        "id": 1073787385,
        "address": null,
        "version": 1675221634311192576,
        "createdBy": 310055,
        "createdByName": "Jeirick Hiponia",
         }
 }
```

}

In the Apps Script development environment, Clicked on Deploy > Test deployments to open the Test deployments dialog.
To load your connector in Looker Studio, replace the <HEAD_DEPLOYMENT_ID> placeholder in the following link with your connector's Head Deployment ID and follow the link in your browser:

[image]

what is the issue?

Comment: Have you checked the stackdriver data to debug or get a reference to the error ? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain more detail?

Comment: I think main issue is getconfig().